Part of the proof is done for lim inf, I need to do it for lim sup.
I have this proof from a book:

I want to fill in the details I have in red.
Attempt:
I get $-f \le -g_{i+1}\le -g_{i} \le \alpha$. From this we get:
$\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} E[-f(X_n)]\le \liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} E[-g_i(X_n)]=E[-g_i(X)]$.
Since $\lim\limits_{i \rightarrow \infty} E[-g_i(X)]=E[-f(X)]$. We get:
$\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}  E[-f(X_n)]\le -E[f(x)]$.
Since we have:
$\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} E(-f(X_n))=-\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}  E[f(X_n)]$, we get:
$-\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}  E[f(X_n)]\le -E[f(x)],$
hence
$\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}  E[f(X_n)]\ge E[f(x)].$
But this is the opposite inequality of what we need. Do you see how to solve this?

$f$ is bounded continuous, so $-f$ is also bounded continuous and you can apply the exact same argument in the book to get
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}E\{-f(X_n)\} \geq E\{-f(X)\}.$$
Multiplying both sides by $-1$ gives the required inequality with $\limsup$.
